# Use same category labeling criteria on two different dataframes

Tags: pandas, label-encoding

I have a dataFrame that contains a categorical feature which i have encoded in the following way:

```
df['categorical_feature'] = df['categorical_feature'].astype('category')
df['labels'] = df['categorical_feature'].cat.codes
```

If I apply the same code as above on another dataFrame with same category field the mapping is shuffled, but i need it to be consistent with the first dataFrame.

Is there a way to successfully apply the same mapping `category:label` to another dataFrame that has the same categorical values?

Comment: Please share a sample of both dataframes with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`pd.Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), which maps values from `category` to `label` using a dictionary that has `category: label` mappings.

**Create mapping dictionary**: You can do this using a dictionary comprehension in combination with `zip`, but there also other ways of doing this:

```
col = 'categorical_features'
mapping_dict = {k: v for k, v in zip(df[col], df[col].cat.codes}
```

Now you can map that `category: label` mapping:

```
df['labels'] = df['categorical'].map(mapping_dict)
```