# Pandas Dataframe : Using same category codes on different existing dataframes with same category

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have two pandas dataframes with some columns in common. These columns are of type category but unfortunately the category codes don't match for the two dataframes. For example I have:

```
>>> df1
     artist          song
0  The Killers   Mr Brightside
1  David Guetta  Memories
2  Estelle       Come Over
3  The Killers   Human


>>> df2  
     artist      date
0  The Killers   2010
1  David Guetta  2012
2  Estelle       2005
3  The Killers   2006
```

But:

```
>>> df1['artist'].cat.codes
0           55
1           78
2           93
3           55
```

Whereas:

```
>>> df2['artist'].cat.codes
0           99
1           12
2           23
3           99
```

What I would like is for my second dataframe `df2` to take the same category codes as the first one `df1` without changing the category values. Is there any way to do this?

(Edit)

Here is a screenshot of my two dataframes. Essentially I want the `song_tags` to have the same cat codes for `artist_name` and `track_name` as the `songs` dataframe. Also `song_tags` is created from a merge between `songs` and another `tag` dataframe (which contains song data and their tags, without the user information) and then saved and loaded through pickle. Also it might be relevant to add that I had to cast `artist_name` and `track_name` in `song_tags` to type `category` from type `object`.

[image: Dataframes]

I think essentially my question is: **how to modify category codes of an existing dataframe column?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61408095/use-same-category-labeling-criteria-on-two-different-dataframes

Comment: It will be helpful if you can show all columns for both dataframes. you can add that in your original question.. You can do that  by either by using `df1.columns` and `df2.columns`  or you can give a snapshot of your data by using `df.head() ` and `df2.head()`

Comment: @sandertjuh I tried this but I didn't manage to make it work with my dataframes. It seems that the answer only uses one dataframe so I'm not sure how this applied to my case.

Comment: @Deepak I can do that, but the dataframes were more examples to illustrate my problem. I'm not sure I understand why showing all columns would help with this issue.

Comment: @beepboop I am just trying to understand how you are getting those values from this `df2['artist'].cat.codes` , more importantly I am more interested on `artist` column of your dataframe

Comment: @Deepak I think the difference may be linked to the fact that for df2 I cast `artist` from an `object` column to a `category` column. I think essentially my question is: can we modify category codes of an existing dataframe column? and if so, how? As from the link above I can create a mapping from artist to the desired category code but I can't find how to apply it to the current category codes.